# The type of foldr (.) id

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to figure out the type of the expression :

```
foldr (.) id
```

GHCI gives me :

```
foldr (.) id :: Foldable t => t (b -> b) -> b -> b
```

And I can't figure this out. foldr type is  `Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b.` 
So it takes 3 parameters as input. So i thought that `foldr (.) id` should take a single parameter as input. Can someone explain how to analyze the type of this expresion ?

Comment: It helps to be more formal. `foldr` takes (like all functions) *one* argument, and returns a function. The type of that function is determined by the type of its argument.

Comment: Here is a closely-related phenomenon that may also be worth thinking about, because it has much less distracting baggage. We have `undefined :: a`, whose type appears to take no arguments. Yet treating it like it's a function and applying it to an argument, as in `undefined ()`, also typechecks. Why?

Comment: by `foldr`'s definition, the types of **`z`** and `foldr g` **`z`** `xs` are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR answer:

```hs
foldr (.) id :: Foldable t => t (b -> b) -> b -> b
```

DOES take one argument. It takes a  `t (b -> b)` and returns a `b -> b`.

This confusion is usually due to Haskell allowing the omission of parens in type signatures. Parens in types associate to the right. So another way to look at this:

```hs
foldr        :: Foldable t => (a -> r -> r) -> (r       -> (t  a       ->  r))
(.) :: (c -> d) -> (b -> c) -> (b -> d)
--        a     ->    r     ->    r
(.) :: (c -> c) -> (b -> c) -> (b -> c)
foldr (.)    :: Foldable t =>                  (b -> c) -> (t (c -> c) -> (b -> c))
id           ::                                 b -> b
foldr (.) id :: Foldable t =>                               t (b -> b) -> (b -> b)
```

You could

```hs
resultFun = foldr (.) id [(+1), (*4)]
resultFun 5
>>> 21
```

Or even

```hs
foldr (.) id [(+1), (*4)] 5
>>> 21
```

Comment: I see - it seems to me that a function that takes maximum number of arguments that is M, can be fed with N < M arguments and the new function created MAY have the maximum number of input arguments > M. Good to know! Thanks!!

Comment: @GilShafriri I think the concept of "maximum number of arguments" is a bit slippery. When the type "returned" is suitably polymorphic, the types it is polymorphic over includes function types.

Answer (score 8):

The type `Foldable t => t (b -> b) -> b -> b` reads as:

- (`Foldable t => ...`) Choose any list-like "container" type `t`,
- (`t (b -> b) -> ...` ) then provide as an argument a `t`-container of functions `b -> b`,
- (`b -> b`) the final result will be a function `b -> b`.

So, it's only slightly more general than: "give me a list of functions, and I will produce a function".

Indeed, when we use lists as containers:

```
foldr (.) id [f1,f2,f3,...,fn]
```

results, by definition of `foldr`, in

```
f1 . (f2 . (f3 .  ... (fn . id) ...))
```

which is the composition of all the functions in the list.

> So i thought that `foldr (.) id` should take a single parameter as input.

It does: the argument has type `t (b -> b)`. Every function in Haskell takes a single parameter as input. E.g.

```
foo :: T -> U -> W -> Z
```

takes `T` and returns a function `U -> W -> Z`.
Now, we can *also* say that `foo` takes two arguments of type `T` and `U` and returns a function `W -> Z`. Or That it takes three arguments `T`, `U`, and `W`, and returns a `Z`. There is no real difference between these interpretations of a type, thanks to currying, so we can pick the one which is the easiest to grasp.

In your case, the result type of `foldr (.) id` is `b -> b`, so one usually interprets the first `b` as an additional argument. This does not provide a good intuition, though. It's easier to think of `b -> b` being the result type.

---

More technically: the type of `foldr` is (renaming variables for clarity).

```
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> c -> c) -> c -> t a -> c
```

In `foldr (.) id`, we can see that the type of the second argument is `id :: b -> b`, hence we are using `c = (b -> b)`, as if we specialized the above type to:

```
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> (b -> b) -> (b -> b)) -> (b -> b) -> t a -> (b -> b)
```

Now, the first argument must have type `(.) :: (a -> (b -> b) -> (b -> b))` to type check. This is possible only if `a = (b -> b)`. Hence, we specialize again.

```
foldr :: Foldable t => 
         ((b -> b) -> (b -> b) -> (b -> b)) ->
         (b -> b) -> 
         t (b -> b) ->
         (b -> b)
```

which is the final type: after this specialization, `foldr` can then be applied to `(.)` and `id`.

All the specializations above are inferred automatically by GHC from your code. Essentially, GHC chooses `a` and `c` in the only way that can make your code type check

Comment: The way I read foldr (.) id :: Foldable t => t (b -> b) -> b -> b  is that the first argument is  t (b -> b) and the second is b so it accept 2 arguments

Comment: @GilShafriri Any function which "accepts N arguments" in Haskell also "accepts M arguments" for any M<N. E.g. `(+)` accepts 2 arguments, as in `(+) 4 5` resulting in `9`. Still `(+) 4` type checks, and is a function which adds 4 to its input. This is currying and partial application in action. Technically, "taking more than one argument" is only an illusion: we only have functions taking one argument, and then returning functions taking another argument, and so on.

Comment: I meant the maximum number of arguments that can be fed to it is 2.

Comment: @GilShafriri Ah, right. That's another issue, caused by polymorphic functions whose return type is a type variable like `c` (`foldr :: .... -> c`), and that can therefore be specialized to a function, making "another" argument to appear. Consider `id :: c -> c`, which is simpler. How many args at most? One would say one. However `id succ` is the same as `succ`, which is a function, hence `id succ 2` type checks and evaluates to `3` (like `succ 2`). But `id succ 2` passes _two_ arguments to `id`. Worse, you can try `id id id id .... id 2` and observe that it type checks. No max number of args!

Comment: @GilShafriri So, briefly put, if a function (like `foldr` or `id`) once provided with N args can return a function, then other arguments can be passed, "making the number of arguments to increase", so to speak. This is a consequence of polymorphism which is rather surprising. In general there is no "max number of args" for a polymorphic function.